# Problems with string.split()

Tags: python

I have a problem where the below-stated function is supposed to extract data from the file (the content of which is also showcased below), into three lists.

The problem is that if I run the program, only the rows that do not contain any numbers with the decimal point are showcased in the result.

```
def extract(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as data:
        rows = data.readlines()
    data_1 = []
    data_2 = []
    data_3 = []
    for row in rows:
        try:
            data_1.append(int(row.split()[0]))
            data_2.append(int(row.split()[1]))
            data_3.append(int(row.split()[2]))
            print(row.split())
        except ValueError:
            pass
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return (data_1, data_2, data_3)
```

The contents of said file:

```
-90   0.76     0.01
-85   3.16     0.01
-80   11.0     0.1
-75   20.5     0.1
-65   53.9     0.1  
-60   74.5     0.1
-55   97.8     0.1
-50   126.3    0.1
-45   167      1
-40   183      1
-35   214      1
-30   222      1
-25   243      1
-20   264      1
-15   287      1
-10   295      1
-5    309      1
0     309      1
5     285      1
10    289      1
15    268      1
20    259      1
25    237      1
30    222      1
35    214      1
40    172      1
45    139      1
50    118      1
55    90       1
60    70       1
65    48.6     0.5
70    30.5     0.2
75    15.63    0.05
80    7.25     0.05
85    2.08     0.01
90    1.00     0.01
```

Comment: Connvert to `float` instead of `int` if the values may contain decimal places?

Comment: It seems like your file is table file. Why don't you use pandas?

Comment: It also seems like experimental data, you realy should try pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Using `int` removes the decimal part:

```
>>> int(2.4)
2
```

You may need to change your appendage to:

```
data_1.append(float(row.split()[0]))
data_2.append(float(row.split()[1]))
data_3.append(float(row.split()[2]))
```

As `float` is the decimal data type

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea how I overlooked sth like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the try-except, you get the proper diagnose: split produces three strings, but only strings without decimals can be converted to int. Below a code including your extract function, a fixed one, and the approach I would suggest (np.loadtxt):

```
import numpy as np

def extract2(fin):
    with open(fin, 'r') as data:
        rows = data.readlines()
    data_1 = []
    data_2 = []
    data_3 = []
    for row in rows:
        sd1, sd2, sd3 = row.split()
        data_1.append(int(float(sd1)))
        data_2.append(int(float(sd2)))
        data_3.append(int(float(sd3)))
    return (data_1, data_2, data_3)

def extract(fin):
    with open(fin, 'r') as data:
        rows = data.readlines()
    data_1 = []
    data_2 = []
    data_3 = []
    for row in rows:
        try:
            data_1.append(int(row.split()[0]))
            data_2.append(int(row.split()[1]))
            data_3.append(int(row.split()[2]))
            print(row.split())
        except ValueError:
            pass
        except TypeError:
            pass
    return (data_1, data_2, data_3)


fin = 'test.txt'
d1, d2, d3 = extract(fin)
da1, da2, da3 = extract2(fin)

data1, data2, data3 = np.loadtxt(fin, unpack=True)
data2 = data2.astype(np.int32)
print(da2)
print(data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("yourFile", sep="\s+", header=None, names=["a", "b", "c"])
a, b, c = df.a.tolist(), df.b.tolist(), df.c.tolist()
```

if you use pandas, then "a, b, c" are the lists.